# Mean of a continuous random variable for which density function follows a normal distribution

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, means

Mean of a continuous random variable is given by :

[image]

where density function is given by

[image]

My question is how can I calculate the mean of a continuous random variable when the density function takes the mean itself as a parameter. And that density function is required to calculate the value of the mean.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to start with the formula for the density and prove that $\mu$ is indeed the mean. You are not supposed to assume that $f$ here stands for a pdf with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma ^{2}$.

Here is the proof: $\int xf(x) dx=\int (x-\mu) f(x)dx+ \mu \int f(x) dx$. The first term is $\int yf(y+\mu) dy$ by the change of variable $y=x-\mu$. This inetgral is $0$ because the integrand is an odd function. Hence we are left with $0+(\mu )1=\mu$. I have only used the fact that $f$ is a density function.

Comment: Hi does μ in this case equals to sum of all observations over total number of observations?

Comment: I mean can I calculate μ for continuous variable by summation of all values over total values? as you have proved that mean is equal to μ

Comment: For a continuous r.v. $X$ with pdf $f$ the  mean is $EX=\int xf(x)dx$. I have applied this definition and used the fact that integral of  sum of two functions is the sum of the integrals of those functions. @AhmadFarhan

Comment: I think i am unable to clarify my question. If a continuous r.v.'s probability density function follows a normal distribution. its f is given by the formula i have written in my question right? I am confused by the fact that density function is taking mean as a parameter . whereas same density function is used to calculate the mean itself? How?